# see him last or last see him?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? And which is better to use in a formal speech?

- when did you see him ***last***?

or

- when did you ***last*** see him?

or

- when did the ***last time*** you see him?

Comment: The first two are grammatically correct, because they are questions about a verb that is not *to be*, and we use *do* to ask questions about verbs like that.  The last one is not grammatically correct, because it is asking a question about *to be*, and we don't use *do* to ask *to be* questions.

Comment: Putting adverbial ***last*** at the *end* of the question (the first example above) is increasingly becoming "dated / literary / stylised", and should probably be avoided. Definitely don't reflect that sequence with an answer like *I saw him last on Thursday*. That version went out with the Victorians - today, it's always *I **last saw** him on Thursday*.

Answer (score 3):

The first two are fine. The second slightly suggests (to me) more concern about just when the seeing took place.

The third is wrong. You could say

> When was the last time you saw him?

That would seem to me a more formal request about that time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the positioning of adverbial ***last*** in OP's first example is on the way out. There are closely-related contexts where it's already manifestly unacceptable (or at least, "marked") to many if not most native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Fair enough - not something I knew.

Comment: It wasn't something I "knew" until I thought about it. I came to the conclusion that usage definitely ***is*** changing in this area, after which I created [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+last+saw+him+on%2CI+saw+him+last+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=30), which I think bears out my idea.